# What does the symbol X mean in the definition of the covariance matrix specifically?

Tags: statistics, covariance

I just started to learn the covariance matrix in some machine learning online course. The following is the covariance matrix definition from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix

[image: covariance matrix definition]

I can see that the X are defined as the random variables in the column vector

[image: random variables in the column vector]

From my understanding, it seems that the X is the vector. However, when I searched on the google , I found it seems that the X is the matrix. Each column of the matrix represents one observation and each row represents one dimension.

[image: the X is the matrix]

But when I checked on the wiki, there is no obvious explanation that the X is the matrix.

I would like to ask what the symbol X means in the definition of the covariance matrix specifically ?  the vector or the matrix ? It should be a very basic problem but I can not get the point.

Thank you.

Comment: The wiki article clearly states that  $X$ is a random vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $X$ is a (column) random vector of length $n$. Then $XX^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, where $X^T$ is the transposed vector of $X$. The same holds for the mean vector $\mu_X$.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. If it is a (column) random vector , each entry of the matrix  B=XXT  is Bij = Xi*Xj. What does Bij mean when Xi and Xj are the random value. I can understand when Xi is the actual value but I don't understand when Xi is a random value. How can I calculate the Bij when Xi and Xj are the random value in the real dataset ?

Comment: Its a product of random variable and so also a random variable.